# Broadcast receiver when user deactivates Location Permission in Android app?

Tags: android, location, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions, intentfilter

I've been hunting for the IntentFilter to use to register for a broadcast for when a user turns on or off their in app location permission (Settings-Apps & Notifications->select your app to listen on->Permissions->Location).

Is there any way to listen for a change to that?

In other words, turning on or turning off the permission, I want my app to be notified.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to listen for a change to that?

No. Your process is terminated; the next time your app runs, when you call `checkSelfPermission()`, you will find out that the runtime permission was revoked.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it can be. Add it to the Intent filter like this filter.addAction(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION); Then check that case like this: case LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION:

Comment: @user443654: Are you sure that you are revoking the permission, and not disabling locations for the device?

Comment: I'll verify tomorrow. A team member just sent this to me saying it was working for them. I'll post back once I am certain one way or the other.